# Training and simulating a spatstat ppm using multiple datasets

Tags: r, spatstat

**Disclaimer:  I'm very new to spatstat and spatial point modeling in general... please excuse my naivete.**

I have recently tried using spatstat to fit and simulate spatial point patterns related to weather phenomenon where the spatial pattern represents a set of eye-witness reports (for example, reports of hail occurrence) and the observational window and covariate is based on some meteorological parameter (eg. the window is area where moisture is at least X, and then the moisture variable is additionally passed as a covariate when training the model).

```
moistureMask = owin(mask=moisture>X)
moistureVar = im(moisture)

obsPPP = ppp(x=obsX,y=obsY,window=moistureMask)
myModel = ppm(obsPPP ~ moistureVar)

### then simulate
mySim = simulate(myModel,nsim=10)
```

My questions are the following:

1. Is it possible (or more importantly, even valid), to take a ppm trained on one day with a specific moisture variable and mask, and apply it to another day with a different moisture value and mask.  I had considered using the `update` function to switch out the window and covariate fields from the trained  model, but haven't actually tried it yet. If the answer is yes... its a little unclear to me how to actually do this, programmatically
2. Is it it possible to do an online update of the ppm with additional data.  For example, train the model on data from different days (each with their own window and covariate), iteratively (similar to how many machine learning models are trained, using blocks of training data).  For example, lets say I have 10-years of daily data which I'd like to use to train the model, and another 10-years of moisture variables over which I'd like to simulate point patterns.  Again, I considered the `update` function here as well, but it was unclear if the new model would simply be based ONLY on the new data, or a combination of the original and new data.

Please let me know if I'm going the completely wrong direction with this.  References and resources appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fitted a model using `ppm` and you update it by specifying new data and/or new covariates, then the new data replace the old data; the updated model's parameters are determined using only the new data that you gave when you called `update`.

The syntax for the `update` command is described in the online help for `update.ppm` (the method for the generic `update` for an object of class `ppm`).

It seems that what you really want to do is to fit a point process model to many replicate datasets, each dataset consisting of a predictor `moistureVar` and a point pattern `obsPPP`. In that case, you should use the function `mppm` which fits a point process model to replicated data.

To do this, first make a list `A` containing the moisture regions for each day, and another list `B` containing the hail report location patterns for each day. That is, `A[[1]]` is the moisture region for day 1, and `B[[1]]` is the point pattern of hail report locations for day 1, and so on. Then do

```
   h <- hyperframe(moistureVar=A, obsPPP=B)
   m <- mppm(obsPPP ~ moistureVar, data=h)
```

This will fit a single point process model to the full set of data.

Finally can I point out that the model

```
  obsPPP ~ moistureVar
```

is very simple, because `moistureVar` is a binary predictor. The model will simply say that the intensity of hail reports takes one value inside the high-moisture region, and another value outside that region. As an alternative, you could consider use the moisture content (eg humidity) as a predictor variable.

See Chapters 9 and 16 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks Adrian... Indeed this is what I realized after working through the problem yesterday and using your thorough documentation!  Thanks for the confirmation!  I am looking into purchasing the text book today as it seems like in invaluable resource.  I'll also link to the [pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/vignettes/replicated.pdf) from the R-cran you put together as an initial primer on replicated point patterns.